# Add In Plot Labels to Seaborn Lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that shows monthly revenue. There is an additional column that shows the number of locations opened in that month.

```
>       Date        Order Amount    Locations Opened 
  16    2016-05-31  126443.17       2.0
> 17    2016-06-30  178144.27       0.0 
  18    2016-07-31  230331.96       1.0
> 19    2016-08-31  231960.04       0.0 
  20    2016-09-30  208445.26       0.0
```

I'm using seaborn to plot the revenue by month

```
    sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Order Amount", 
                data=total_monthly_rev).set_title("Total Monthly Revenue")
```

[image]

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, to use the third column, Locations Opened, to add supporting text to the lineplot so I can show the number of locations opened in a month, where Locations Opened > 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, use `text`:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Order Amount", data=total_monthly_rev).set_title("Total Monthly Revenue")

# Using a variable to manage how above/below text should appear
slider = 1000
for i in range(total_monthly_rev.shape[0]):
    if total_monthly_rev['LocationsOpened'].iloc[i] > 0:
        plt.text(total_monthly_rev.Date.iloc[i], 
                 total_monthly_rev['Order Amount'].iloc[i] + slider,  
                 total_monthly_rev['LocationsOpened'].iloc[i])
plt.show()
```

[image: plt]